# Change the default value of MySQL global variables in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, wamp

Working on local environment with Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP, I usually debug SQL using the log files with the help of this 2 global settings:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
SET GLOBAL general_log_file = 'my_log.log';
```

The problem is these settings go away after a while.

I originally thought it makes a difference with what user they are set but not when I tested, **the global variables get reseted on MySQL restart**, which is common on WAMPP environment.

I tried to update `my.ini`, `my-default.ini` adding the following settings:

```
 general_log = 'ON';
 general_log_file = 'my_log.log';
```

But with no effect.

What is the proper way to change the default settings for MySQL in a WAMPP installation?

Answer (score 0):

These entries in the `my.ini` file should work

```
#set general-log = 0 to turn off
# or log-output = NONE
general-log
log-output = FILE
general_log_file = "C:/xampp/path/to/general-query.log"
```